# how can I manipulate data frame based on several columns strings

Tags: r

I want to make all the strings in col1 , col2 , col3 and col4 unique and then bring their res value in front of it. so the output is look like this

I want to have output like this

```
output <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 27L, 18L, 
26L, 25L, 24L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 
15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 19L, 20L), .Label = c("A8WFJ8", "A8WFK2", 
"A8WHR6", "A8WHS3", "A8WIT0", "A8XQE0", "A9D0C6", "A9D4S6", "A9D649", 
"A9D8E6", "A9UJN4", "A9Z1L6", "ADliba1", "ADNIL2", "B0M0N9", 
"DFGH2", "GDH76", "ML2IS5", "Q9XXL6", "Q9XXN0", "Q9XXN2", "Q9XXQ4", 
"Q9XXQ6", "QSEA12", "RR2JDG", "T2HDY3", "TR5421"), class = "factor"), 
    res1 = c(3.59e-08, 2.15e-08, 1.52e-07, 1.24e-07, 4.53e-08, 
    3.11e-08, 7.08e-08, 1.98e-08, 1.46e-08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), res2 = c(8.11e-07, 7.21e-08, 
    0, 4.02e-08, 0, 0, 2.32e-08, 0, 1.46e-08, 3.86e-08, 2.68e-08, 
    2.7e-08, 7.76e-08, 7.76e-08, 7.76e-08, 7.76e-08, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), res3 = c(8.76e-08, 1.4e-07, 0, 2.8e-08, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.85e-08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.13e-08, 3.57e-08, 
    1.46e-07, 5.23e-08, 6.44e-08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), res4 = c(1.42e-07, 
    8.66e-08, 0, 7.64e-08, 0, 0, 6.28e-07, 0, 0, 0, 7.25e-07, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.26e-05, 8.58e-08, 2.83e-08, 
    3.7e-08, 1.26e-05, 8.58e-08)), .Names = c("col1", "res1", 
"res2", "res3", "res4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

Comment: How did you end up with `df` in the first place? I think if at all possible you should go back one step and try to avoid making such unusual data in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure the original `df` is correct?  The names for the columns are `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, ... and the first line is `col1`, `res1`, `col2`, ...  Also only 13 out of your 46 rows have any data in them at all.

Comment: @Barker I corrected it , sorry for the mistake. please look at above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by cleaning up the data

```
# organizes your "col" and "res" values into different lists
splitDF <- lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by = 2), 
                  function(x) df[x:(x+1)])
# renames first column to make it easier for the merge
splitDF <- lapply(splitDF, function(x) names(x)[1] <- "col1")
# removes blank lines
splitDF <- lapply(splitDF, function(x) x[complete.cases(x), ])
```

Then you can use the great merge solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) to gather into one data frame.

```
output <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), splitDF)
```

Finally you can set all of the `NA` values to zero and reorder the rows.

```
output[is.na(output)] <- 0
varOrder <- c("ADliba1", "ADNIL2", "DFGH2", "GDH76", "TR5421", "ML2IS5",
              "T2HDY3", "RR2JDG", "QSEA12", "A8WHS3", "A9D0C6", "A9D649", 
              "A9UJN4", "Q9XXN2", "Q9XXQ4", "Q9XXQ6", "A8WIT0", "A9D4S6",
              "A9D8E6", "A9Z1L6", "B0M0N9", "A8WFJ8", "A8WFK2", "A8WHR6", 
              "A8XQE0", "Q9XXL6", "Q9XXN0")
output <- output[match(varOrder, output[["col1"]]), ]
```

Comment: I already loved your solution, however , before i accept it, I would like to know if you could do it in a way that the order of the column does not change. look at the top of the `output`you see it is not the same as df1, is it possible? if no, I will accept your answer anyway

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the order of the column does not change".  Since you have different but overlapping values in your four `col` columns there isn't really a clear definition of order I can see.  If you can define "order" I will see if I can figure out a solution.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. my mean look at the first col, can it stay as it is and not arrange differently? do you get my point ? if no, please let me know I will show it above. Please also don't down vote my question, you already answered it , so I am gonna like and accept your answer

Comment: Is there something that makes the order of `col` in your value of `output` the correct order or is it an arbitrary definition?  I can probably find a solution either way, but if it isn't arbitrary, I would rather try and make something generalizable so it is more useful to others.

Comment: it is arbitrary. ok, I like and accept your answer. thanks. can you also add some definition to the code line ? so that i understand what you did